# google map api marker not added in browser

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add marker on google map when a mouse event occurs . Map is displayed but marker not added on mouse click event. making map variable global also didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<!-- loading google map api -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<!-- exact map api script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.0, 84.0),
      zoom: 4
    };
    <!-- Map constructor creates a new map inside a given html container,typically a div -->
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

    //click event on map with event argument pass
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click' ,function(e){
        placeMarker(e.latLng,map);
    });
}//initialize function ends
    function placeMarker(position, map){
        var marker=google.maps.Marker({
        position:position,
        map:map
        });
    map.panTo(position);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `new` keyword when you are creating your marker:

```
var marker = google.maps.Marker({ // <-- see this line
    position: position,
    map: map
});
```

Change it to:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: position,
    map: map
});
```

and it works.

Cheers.

Comment: in the mapOptions variable I added this line of code to change the map type    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP and its not working showing blank

Comment: @TaraGurung generally speaking, thats already a different question ;) but, please use google chrome and developer console. You should google about it, it will tell you where you have an error.. ROADMAP is selected by default so you dont need to tell it, however, even if you do. It should not be blank if you modify your code be as: var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.0, 84.0),
      zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };